# ngClick events not firing in Angular 1.5.5 component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why doesn't clicking the button described in the template below work as expected? [This blog post does the exact same thing](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/).

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').component('foo', {
    bindings: {
        items: '<',
    },
    controller: function() {
        function fire() {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    },
    template: "<button type='button' ng-click='$ctrl.fire();'>Test</button>"
});
```

Edit: Added more clarity to the question

Comment: *"Why doesn't this work as expected?"*. No one knows what you expect and what you get.

Comment: Is the title and the context of the code not enough to deduce that I'd expect a message to be logged to the console?

Comment: It is but it's better to explain it in the post body. Like I for example missed title. Anyway, Amir has answered it correctly.

Comment: Got it. I'll do that in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `fire` is not exposed on the controller.

```
this.fire = fire;
```